# Conflict between video loading and <body onload>

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a web page where I have got a video at the top of the `<body>`. I want to scroll to an element just below this video at page loading.

So I use:

```
<body onload="scrollSomewhere();">
```

My `scrollSomewhere()` is correctly launched but only once the video starts to play. The scroll does not occur until the video starts to play.

Do you see how to solve this problem? Async playing of the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body.onload` waits for the entire body to load, including external resources like video, images and other things.

If you want the function to execute before everything is loaded, there's the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, that fires as soon as all elements are present in the DOM, and doesn't wait for each element to load it's resources etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", scrollSomewhere, false);
</script>
```

You could also just call the function directly, for instance in a script tag right before the `</body>` tag etc.

Comment: The hack with calling it just before the `<body>` is more portable for older browsers